# ILLEGALSTATEEXCEPTION : Target host must not be null

Tags: java, android

I have tried multiple solutions here but none seem to work. I am getting error at  `String imageJsonStr = sh2.makeServiceCall(imgUrl[i], ServiceHandler.GET);`
There are no special characters in string and variable `imageId` is a string containing only numbers like '98546214265231'

```
                             imgUrl[i] = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/"
                                        + imageId
                                        + "?access_token="
                                        + static_token;                                                 
                                try {

                                    try {
                                        imgUrl[i] = URLEncoder.encode(imgUrl[i],"UTF-8");
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    String imageJsonStr = sh2.makeServiceCall(
                                            imgUrl[i], ServiceHandler.GET);
```

Comment: log the value of imgUrl[i] after encoding it using  URIEncoder ..

Comment: https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fv2.2%2F%5BLjava.lang.String%3B%4042477c08%3Faccess_token%3DCAAK43Qt9dQUBAF0ZC3LYE828xyaaQgTccYYpWBmO7sqcsll4S3lhnVdBH0JrV30qPjjLWPwy0lPR0ZAt8Tsl5se0OGWWQejybyEWZCmPXJdjBhorBNWAudWXEZAuVaQnrpMkmcZAGsGO31aIHZA8SttfEkEi4rntmIweZBluWJ2ZAHi40tqiiXZCp***********************************************

Comment: so u have to encode only your url parameters..the whole uri could not be encoded..

Comment: I can also do it manually right? like this ?"access_token%33DCAAK43Qt9dQUBAF0ZC3LYE***..."

Comment: i think that  will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) refer this.. you need not encode the entire url .. encode only the parmaters

Comment: do i need to encode Url even if there are no special characters after '?' ?

Comment: if there is no special characters then no need to encode..special chars includes spaces also..parameter encoding will be safe..

Comment: I removed `URLEncoder`. I am getting "Illegal character in path at " starting of `imageId` .My `imageId` is a string containg all numbers

Comment: if your accesstoken doesn't have any spaces try this. don't do any encoding stuffs

Comment: yes removing URLEncoder solved that problem. can you please tell me why am I getting "Illegal character in path" ?